# Centering a DIV containing floated images

Tags: html, center

I'm having trouble centering this on my page, I've done some research and it seems that using "inline-block" may be the way to go, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Here is my code:

**CSS**

```
.bar img{
    float:left;
    margin: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
}
.bar img:hover {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div align = "center">
    <img src = "images/wk5title.png">
</div>

<!--THIS IS WHAT IM TRYING TO CENTER-->
<div class = "bar" style="margin : auto; text-align: center">
    <a href = "fb.html"><img src="images/fb.png"></a>
    <a href = "tw.html"><img src="images/tw.png"></a>
    <a href = "li.html"><img src="images/li.png"></a>
    <a href = "da.html"><img src="images/da.png"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You're trying to center the div containing your images, or the images within the div?

Answer (score 0):

Define a width and then use the `margin:auto` you have. This automatically centers the element in the center of the page. You should also really change `<body background = "images/wk5bg.png" bgcolor = "#eeeeee">` to use CSS.

```
body {
    background-image:url(image/wk5bg.png);
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
div .bar {
    width:(your width here);
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added another **div** inside **.bar** for **table** and **table-cell**. The table is getting centered and the cell is shrinking around the content.
Also, I replaced the image margins with padding for hover to work even after the animation and added padding-bottom to compensate for the raise.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZW9YB/

```
<div align="center">
    <img src="images/wk5title.png" />
</div>

<!--THIS IS WHAT IM TRYING TO CENTER-->
<div class="bar"><div>
    <a href="fb.html"><img src="images/fb.png" /></a>
    <a href="tw.html"><img src="images/tw.png" /></a>
    <a href="li.html"><img src="images/li.png" /></a>
    <a href="da.html"><img src="images/da.png" /></a>
</div></div>

.bar img {
    float:left;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: padding 0.5s ease-out;
}

.bar {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.bar > div {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #faa;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bar:after {
    clear: both;
}

.bar img:hover {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 28px;
}
```